# how to wrap non maven jar using pax-wrap-jar

Tags: java, maven, osgi, pax

I have a jar from an old application that I want to use in the new project I am working on. I am using OSGI with pax. I know that with pax-wrap-jar we can create a bundle with a jat from maven repo, but my jar is in my local computer so I don't see how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Figure out how to make your jar a maven artifact.  Mvn install:install-file may be a way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install that local jar to your remote repository

Answer (score 0):

the Pax-Wrap jar just ads another url-handler to your osgi env, so just combine it with the wrap handler.
For example:

```
wrap:file:location-to-file/jar.jar
```